# Android: Error inflating class ImageView on pre Lollipop (SDK 16) when using a custom drawable?

Tags: java, android, imageview

I just testet my app on a SDK 16 device and on the emulator and both times I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                                 at com.eliburgi.foodallergydiary.ui.diarypage.adapters.DrinkEntryBulletAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(DrinkEntryBulletAdapter.java:53)
                                                                                 at com.eliburgi.foodallergydiary.ui.diarypage.adapters.DrinkEntryBulletAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(DrinkEntryBulletAdapter.java:23)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6367)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5555)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3025)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                                 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
                                                                                 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.measureChildWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:8636)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1577)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1795)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.jav
```

On SDK 21 and higher everything works fine but for earlier versions the program fails parsing the below ImageView:

```
<ImageView
        style="@style/BulletListItemIcon.Drink"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_diary_entry_bullet_keyline"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_left_diary_entry_bullet_keyline" />
```

In styles.xml:

```
<style name="BulletListItemIcon">
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/icon_small</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/icon_small</item>
    </style>

<style name="BulletListItemIcon.Drink">
        <item name="srcCompat">?attr/iconBackgroundDrink</item>
    </style>
```

`?attr/iconBackgroundDrink` is defined in the AppTheme used for this app:

```
<item name="iconBackgroundDrink">@drawable/bg_drink_icon_gradient</item>
```

In `bg_drink_icon_gradient.xml`:

```
<shape android:shape="oval"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:angle="135"
    android:startColor="@color/drink_gradient"
    android:endColor="@color/drink_gradient_dark"
    android:type="linear" />

    <stroke android:color="@color/icon_border" android:width="@dimen/border_width_icons"/>

</shape>
```

Somehow everything works fine when using a color instead of a drawable:

```
<style name="BulletListItemIcon.Drink">
        <item name="srcCompat">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

It even works if using a SVG drawable:

```
<style name="BulletListItemIcon.Drink">
        <item name="srcCompat">@drawable/ic_profile</item>
    </style>
```

In my app´s gradle build I set `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.eliburgi.foodallergydiary"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Using a color or SVG drawable in the above style for the ImageView works fine, but it fails using a custom drawable. I have no clue why this doesn´t work, so I would really appreciate any tips and answers, thanks :)

Comment: Did you tried using src besides srcCompat?

Comment: Yeah. Same error...

Comment: and background? Or backgroundDrawable?

Comment: Same error. Thanks for trying to help me btw :)

Comment: Try to put layout_height and layout_width directly in xml and not in style

Comment: Try removing `layout_marginStart`

Comment: @Dany Poplawec This did not work.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes This also did not work ...

Comment: put src directly in xml instead of style

Comment: @DanyPoplawec Also did not work. Could it be that something is wrong with my custom xml drawable?

Comment: It could be yes

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be some error with my custom XML drawable. I commented out the stroke tag and it works fine. I´ll try a bit what´s missing and let you know.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
    <!--<stroke android:color="@color/icon_border" android:width="@dimen/border_width_icons"/>-->
</shape>
```

If anyone knows what is wrong please let me know.

EDIT: I think I know know what´s causing the error. It´s the following color definition that´s used by all custom XML drawables stroke-tags:

```
<color name="icon_border">?android:colorBackground</color>
```

Can anyone please explain to me why this does not work on SDK 16?

EDIT: It works now. I simply replaced the above color definition with:

```
<color name="app_background">##FFFAFAFA</color>
<color name="icon_border">@color/app_background</color>
```

I´ve set the theme attribute `android:backgroundColor` to my color `app_background`.

Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: Indeed, you can not reference theme attributes inside resource files like colors or drawables before API 21. The exception is vector drawables when using the AppCompat implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I have been experiencing the same issue. The solution was to replace ImageView with android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView